# Can not run git commands in git custom pre-receive hook

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, gitlab-ce

I'm running a copy of `gitlab-ce` on a server of mine and I would like to do a custom `pre-receive` hook that searches for TODOs in the committed code and doesn't allow the push if there are any TODOs found. How can I access the committed code/files if I don't have access to git commands since I'm in the `<project_name>.git` directory and not in the actual code directory?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't have to be *in the actual code directory* to *have access to git commands*. Change `$PATH` if `git` is not accessible.

Comment: Keep in mind server-side hooks can be dangerous. I opted to use client-side hooks + a CI. https://github.com/github/platform-samples/tree/master/pre-receive-hooks#think-twice-before-you-deploy-a-pre-receive-hook

Comment: It's not that. I have access to git, but it tells me this: `this operation must be run in a work tree`. What I try to run is `git-diff-index` command.